# Why does this while loop execute infinite times?

Tags: java, do-while

I have a while loop which should read through elements of an array to try and find the value of the given `variable`, however, the loop executes itself infinite times and I can't see why. It should exit once it has found the value it is looking for; I know it does find what it's looking for because it prints out `I've found it!` infinite times.The code for the method, so far is:

```
try{
    System.out.println("Enter your card number to access your account:");
    int CardNumber = sc.nextInt();
    String CardNumberStr = Integer.toString(CardNumber);
    boolean Exist = false;
    String LineNo;
    String [] CardNum = {};
    int Counter;
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("VirtualATM.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    CardNum = line.split("\\s+");
    do{
        for(Counter = 0; Counter < CardNum.length; Counter++){
            LineNo = CardNum[Counter];
            if(LineNo.contains(CardNumberStr)){
                Exist = true;
                System.out.println("I've found it!");
            }
            else if(Counter == CardNum.length){
                Exist=false;
            }
        }
    }while(Exist = false || line != null);
    bufferedReader.close();
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why it does this please?

Comment: I recommend you set Eclipse (or whatever IDE you use) to warn you when you have a boolean assignment in an if/while block.

Comment: could it be while (Exist == false... instead of Exist=false ????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're assigning `Exist = false` in the `do-while` loop. It should be `Exists == false` or way better: `!Exist`:

```
} while(!Exist || line != null);
```

Apart of this, please follow the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) (old but still used), where the variables should be declared with camel case but starting with lower case letters.

---

Reviewing more your code, you're never reading another line of your file and the logic for your `do-while` should use AND (`&&`), not OR (`||`). Just add this to your code:

```
line = bufferedReader.readLine();
CardNum = line.split("\\s+");
do{
    for(Counter = 0; Counter < CardNum.length; Counter++){
        LineNo = CardNum[Counter];
        if(LineNo.contains(CardNumberStr)){
            Exist = true;
            System.out.println("I've found it!");
        }
        else if(Counter == CardNum.length){
            Exist=false;
        }
    }
    //add this line to read another line of the file
    //and check if it exists
    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
} while(!Exist && line != null);
```

Comment: I've changed that and it still goes through the loop infinite times??

Answer (score 2):

Exist = false is the root of all evil here. 
= is the assignment operator and == is the equality comparison operator.

Answer (score 2):

You're not re-reading your `line` variable inside your loop, so `line != null` is always true.

Comment: +1, nice catch, even slipped my eyes. Failed to see that once walking through the code pasted :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another problem:  in

```
    for(Counter = 0; Counter < CardNum.length; Counter++){

        LineNo = CardNum[Counter];
        if(LineNo.contains(CardNumberStr)){
            Exist = true;
            System.out.println("I've found it!");
        }
        else if(Counter == CardNum.length){
            Exist=false;
        }
    }
```

(Counter == CardNum.length) will never be true, since the Count values goes from 0 to CardNum.length-1.  Since Exist is initialized to false, you don't need to set it to false again.  You can drop the else clause.

And by the way, you can break out of the loop

```
    for(Counter = 0; Counter < CardNum.length; Counter++){
        LineNo = CardNum[Counter];
        if(LineNo.contains(CardNumberStr)){
            Exist = true;
            System.out.println("I've found it!");
            break.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wron in this line:

```
while(Exist = false || line != null);
```

It must be:

```
while(Exist == false || line != null);
            ^^^^
```

In you version you assign `false` to `Exist` and you do not compare is.

Answer (score 1):

You are not evaluating Exist against the value false, you are assigning the value false to the variable. It's odd that there isn't more going wrong with the conditional or, there, but you will be able to fix it by setting the line to

```
      while(Exist == false || line != null);
```

I also could be wrong as it is late and I am on an iPad, but is that "while" at the right level of the do? It might need to be one curly bracket up.